# Live DVD vs LiveUSB for dual installation with windows 8

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, live-usb

In the installation tutorial it says liveusb but I am using a livedvd and I assume they are interchangeable. I have a perfectly functioning Ubuntu Trusty Tahr DVD but I am not getting the desired result(It keeps telling me there is no other operating system in the installation). Will using a liveusb for installation make any difference.

Comment: Either way you need to tell the BIOS/UEFI to boot from the installation media. And said media must have been properly done. USB is faster and reusable. Newer release like the current LTS 16.04 is better.

Comment: I succesfully dual-booted ubuntu with windows 7 using the DVD. I guess my question is - Is there something particular about windows 8 that would only work with the LiveUSB